# Decrypting parameters Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, url, encryption, parameters

I have a small problem.
I am sending a mail when an item needs attention.
I am getting the encrypted string, but when I decrypt it I get nothing ..
Anything wrong in my code?
Thanks in advance

Encrypting parameter (ID):

```
$this->load->library('encrypt');
$yes = site_url('job/itemFree/?id='.$this->encrypt->encode($itemid));
$no = site_url('job/itemExtend/?id='.$this->encrypt->encode($itemid));
```

Decrypting :

```
$this->load->library('encrypt');
$id = $_GET['id'];
$id = $this->encrypt->decode($id);
echo $id;
```

Comment: Not sure about this, but I guess there  are some special setting changes that need to be done in CI to properly receive GET parameters, can you check by var_dump($_GET) that you are getting 'id' in it ?

Comment: Could it be that your encrypted strings are not URI-safe? I would use base64encode for uri-safe strings.

Comment: I am getting this as output : array(1) { ["id"]=> string(88) "xxx==" }

Comment: if this code is working then posted code must have same output..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
$this->load->library('encrypt');
$yes = site_url('job/itemFree/?id='.urlencode($this->encrypt->encode($itemid)));
$no = site_url('job/itemFree/?id='.urlencode($this->encrypt->encode($itemid)));
```

Answer (score 0):

instead of passing parameter in id using get you can do it like this

```
$this->load->library('encrypt');
$yes    =   site_url('job/itemFree/'.$this->encrypt->encode($itemid));
$no     =   site_url('job/itemExtend/'.$this->encrypt->encode($itemid));
```

Now to get it you need to do.

```
$this->load->library('encrypt');
$id         =   $this->uri->segment(3);
$decoded_id =   $this->encrypt->decode($id);
echo $decoded_id;
```