# codeigniter encryption not working

Tags: php, codeigniter

I need to pass some encrypted ids(numbers) via `GET` but I couldnt decode some values, here is my code

```
<a href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>mcadmin/loadorder?ODRkey=<?php echo $this->encrypt->encode($orders_list['id']); ?>">
```

`81,83,78` are not working but `76 and 89` are working

CONTROLLER FUNCTION

```
$get = $_GET['ODRkey'];
        $a = $this->encrypt->decode($get);
        echo $a;
```

Answer (score 0):

you can read here :
[Decrypting parameters Codeigniter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20395160/decrypting-parameters-codeigniter)

try to add function urlencode

```
<a href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>mcadmin/loadorder?ODRkey=<?php echo urlencode($this->encrypt->encode($orders_list['id'])); ?>">
```